# How to prove $\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} > \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $x>0$

Tags: inequality, soft-question

How to prove $\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} > \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $x>0$

I tried by using AM-GM inequality.

Can anyone give me some help.

Comment: It's immediate from the generalised Bernoulli inequality (for rational exponents), can you use that?

Comment: @DanielFischer No . I have no idea about it. :(

Comment: If you expand both sides using the Binomial Theorem, there is an extra positive term on the LHS, and all the other terms on the LHS are greater than or equal to corresponding terms on the RHS. This can be shown either quickly and easily, as for instance in J. M. Hyslop, *Real Variable* (1960), p.64, or else messily and awkwardly, as I just found, when I tried to do it without looking at the book. :) Try to find the easy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that using AM-GM, consider
$$a_1=1, a_2 = a_3 = \cdots a_{n+1} = 1+\frac{x}n$$

Now AM-GM gives the strict inequality:
$$1+\frac{x}{n+1} = \frac{1+n(1+\frac{x}n)}{n+1}=\frac{\sum a_i}{n+1} > \sqrt[n+1]{\prod a_i} = \left(1+\frac{x}n \right)^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

Comment: Ah, that takes me back! Durrell and Robson, *Advanced Algebra*, Vol. III (1937), ex. XVb(C)34. :) (Dusting off a lot of old books.)